# More than 100 widgets in single page

Tags: widget, google-workspace-add-ons

According to the workspace addon restriction, we can only have 100 widgets in a single section and altogether 100 sections.
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/guides/workspace-restrictions#have_more_than_100_widgets

According to that, I divided a few widgets into several sections. As an example, 50 widgets in one section and altogether I have 150 widgets. But unfortunately, 3rd section is not visible on the page.

Is there any solution for that or 100 widget restrictions be added to the whole page?

Comment: As the [documentaiton](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/guides/workspace-restrictions#have_more_than_100_widgets) says - the restriction is there for performance reasons. I can imagine that it would not be very user-friendly to have more than this....

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/q/73313385/1595451

Comment: Yes, that's what I want to exactly know. They have a 100-widget limit for the whole page as well. But it isn't mentioned in any documentation. Thank you.